# How to tell if numpy array contains SymPy symbols

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a set of NumPy-based numerical routines and the ability to effortlessly handle symbolic elements is a bonus (but not the main use case).  There are a few instances in the code where it'd be very useful to know if the NumPy array contained symbolic elements.

QUESTION: What is the quickest way to test if a NumPy array contains symbolic elements.

A seemingly quick approach relies on the fact that if there is at any symbolic element then the `dtype` changes to `object` instead of a numeric type.  However, conceivably it could be an array of some other kind of object, not symbolic.  I assume that the array can be heterogeneous in the objects it contains (just reference pointers) so there's no easy way to test what object types it contains apart from iterating over all the elements.

Comment: Exactly right, if it can potentially be a heterogenous array (i.e. with dtype object) then you would *have* to iterate over the entire array and check, there is no other magical way. Why would you even have these in a numpy array to begin with, though?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because the routines are primarily for numeric purposes so numpy is the right tool.  But there are use cases where it makes sense to use them for symbolics, and it works just fine.

Comment: I've seen a number of SO where the problem was the presence of symbols in an array.  Math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss, depending on whether objects implement the right methods.  Symbols do implement most of the same methods as numbers. It's the transcendentals (`np.exp`, `np.sin`) that give a problem for both.  `lambdify` seems to be the safest way to use `sympy` with `numpy/scipy`.

Comment: @hpaulj What is “SO” short for?

Comment: StackOverflow - this board.

Answer (score 0):

In an `isympy` session (previously used for `sympy` SO questions):

```
In [317]: type(y)                                                                                    
Out[317]: sympy.core.symbol.Symbol

In [318]: np.array([1,2,y])                                                                          
Out[318]: array([1, 2, y], dtype=object)

In [319]: np.sum(_)                                                                                  
Out[319]: y + 3

In [320]: type(_)                                                                                    
Out[320]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

So the presence of the `symbol` produces a `sympy` object.

With a different `sympy` object:

```
In [321]: type(x)                                                                                    
Out[321]: sympy.core.function.UndefinedFunction

In [322]: np.sum(np.array([1,2,x]))                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-322-1782e9d730ec> in <module>
----> 1 np.sum(np.array([1,2,x]))

<__array_function__ internals> in sum(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
   2240 
   2241     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
-> 2242                           initial=initial, where=where)
   2243 
   2244 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     85                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     86 
---> 87     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     88 
     89 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'UndefinedFunction'
```

An example of how a symbol mess up a transcendental - something that no one implements as a method.

```
In [323]: np.exp([1,2,3])                                                                            
Out[323]: array([ 2.71828183,  7.3890561 , 20.08553692])

In [324]: np.exp([1,2,y])                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-324-b2dfa5af3395> in <module>
----> 1 np.exp([1,2,y])

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable exp method
```

`None` is a common object dtype element; that will mess up any of these.  `list` elements will often fail with math - except for the few cases where `+` or `*` are defined and used right.

It's probably easier to find ways in which a `sympy` will mess up `numpy` operations, than to identify a clear set of things that work.